# c++ variable value in Auto and Local in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, scope

Why is there a difference between the value of a variable in "Auto" window and in "Local" window when debugging with Visual Studio 13?

At one point in my code I get to:

```
std::vector < std::vector < int >> arm_area; 
arm_area.resize(2, std::vector<int>(int(max_area)));
```

The value of max_area is around 1300, so it should create a 2 by 1300 vector (and according to the "Local" window that works). But in the "Auto" window, arm_area is of size 1437126.

Comment: Is this in optimised release mode?

Comment: Yes it is in release mode